# MySQL stored procedure to take database backup

Tags: mysql, database-backups

Can we write a stored procedure in MySQL to take database backup as we can do in Oracle or Sql Server.

I want to create something like Sql Server Job in MySQL database which will take backup everyday. Can we execute procedure in MySQL Event?

If there is any other option other than this please let me know.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What did google tell you when you asked it about the best mysql backup method?

Comment: When I searched on google, I got option of external tools and cron job as Bill Karwin suggested.
I am new to MySQL, and I weak in unix scripting. Please note that I have written a procedure in Sql Server to take database backup on daily basis.
Just wondering is there any such method in MySQL as well

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Mysql has created this for you allready. Mysqldump is the best option for backing up the data.

Answer (score 2):

I've never seen a stored procedure that can back up a database.  I would recommend not trying to code one yourself, because it's deceptively difficult to get right.

I've seen a number of shell scripts and PHP scripts that claim to create a database dump, but they usually fail in spectacular ways:  not locking tables to ensure consistent snapshot, not handling NULL or not handling character set, not backing up procedures and triggers, etc.

The standard way of backing up on a schedule is to use one of the external tools like mysqldump, mydumper, or Percona XtraBackup, and write a cron job to invoke the preferred tool.